# Joining tables with SAS data integeration studio and keeping all in one row

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, data-integration

I am working with SAS Data Integration Studio and I need to join two tables, but keep all the information of an ID_NAME on the same row.

My data is divided into two tables:

Table 1:

| ID_NAME | NAME | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |

Table 2:

| ID_NAME | ID_TAG | TAG_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Y |
| 1 | 2 | Z |

I would like to join the table 1 and 2 and have something like this:

OBS: the number of tags is unknown, so it can be 0, 1, 2 or any other quantity.

| ID_NAME | NAME | CITY | TAG_NAME_1 | TAG_NAME_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | Y | Z |

Comment: can number of tags be different and more than 2?

Comment: Either do two joins, once for each ID_TAG or Join it and then do a transpose task with ID_TAG.

Comment: @eshirvana SAS SQL is ANSI SQL but it's essentially it's own language. It does not support PIVOT, PARTITION, or OVER.

Comment: @eshirvana the number of tags is unknown, so it can be 0, 1, 2 or any other quantity.

Comment: @Reeza Since the number of tags is unknown, I cannot repeat the joins according to the number of tags, since I can have an ID_NAME with more than 100 tags.

Comment: Then join and TRANSPOSE which doesn't rely on the number of ID_TAGS.